# how to get a div to randomly move around a page (using jQuery or CSS)

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I've been doing some Googling to find an answer to this, but I've had no luck.  It could be because I'm a bit of an amateur and I don't know the proper terms to search for, but maybe someone here can steer me in the right direction or help me out.

Anyway, I'm looking for a way to get a div to randomly, smoothly move around a page.  There will be a background color, then this image which I want to seemingly randomly, infinitely move around the page.  Much like the background of a DVD player's home screen where "DVD" is just floating around.

Starting point of the div doesn't matter, nor does the ending point.  It just needs to randomly move around the page for the duration a user is on that page.

I've got decent HTML and CSS skills, very basic JS skills, and some experience implementing jQuery.  Ideally, I'd like something which I can implement myself.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The basic premise is to generate positional values, and use jquery's animate() function to move the div. The calculation of the next position is simple, you just need a bit of math. Here's a very basic jsfiddle i just knocked up. It could do with possibly a delay timer, a dynamically calculating speed based on how far its got too move e.c.t. But it gives you a start point i hope.

http://jsfiddle.net/Xw29r/

Updated example code with speed modifier:

http://jsfiddle.net/Xw29r/15/

---

For some reason this is still getting some attention, so here's an updated answer that uses CSS transitions which should be much smoother.

http://jsfiddle.net/bf9nv1q6/

```js
function RandomObjectMover(obj, container) {
 this.$object = obj;
  this.$container = container;
  this.container_is_window = container === window;
  this.pixels_per_second = 250;
  this.current_position = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  this.is_running = false;
}

// Set the speed of movement in Pixels per Second.
RandomObjectMover.prototype.setSpeed = function(pxPerSec) {
 this.pixels_per_second = pxPerSec;
}

RandomObjectMover.prototype._getContainerDimensions = function() {
   if (this.$container === window) {
       return { 'height' : this.$container.innerHeight, 'width' : this.$container.innerWidth };
   } else {
       return { 'height' : this.$container.clientHeight, 'width' : this.$container.clientWidth };
   }
}

RandomObjectMover.prototype._generateNewPosition = function() {

 // Get container dimensions minus div size
  var containerSize = this._getContainerDimensions();
 var availableHeight = containerSize.height - this.$object.clientHeight;
  var availableWidth = containerSize.width - this.$object.clientHeight;
    
  // Pick a random place in the space
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableHeight);
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableWidth);
    
  return { x: x, y: y };    
}

RandomObjectMover.prototype._calcDelta = function(a, b) {
 var dx   = a.x - b.x;         
  var dy   = a.y - b.y;         
  var dist = Math.sqrt( dx*dx + dy*dy ); 
  return dist;
}

RandomObjectMover.prototype._moveOnce = function() {
  // Pick a new spot on the page
    var next = this._generateNewPosition();
    
    // How far do we have to move?
    var delta = this._calcDelta(this.current_position, next);
    
  // Speed of this transition, rounded to 2DP
  var speed = Math.round((delta / this.pixels_per_second) * 100) / 100;
    
    //console.log(this.current_position, next, delta, speed);
          
    this.$object.style.transition='transform '+speed+'s linear';
    this.$object.style.transform='translate3d('+next.x+'px, '+next.y+'px, 0)';
    
    // Save this new position ready for the next call.
    this.current_position = next;
  
};

RandomObjectMover.prototype.start = function() {

 if (this.is_running) {
   return;
  }

 // Make sure our object has the right css set
  this.$object.willChange = 'transform';
  this.$object.pointerEvents = 'auto';
 
  this.boundEvent = this._moveOnce.bind(this)
  
  // Bind callback to keep things moving
  this.$object.addEventListener('transitionend', this.boundEvent);
  
  // Start it moving
  this._moveOnce();
  
  this.is_running = true;
}

RandomObjectMover.prototype.stop = function() {

 if (!this.is_running) {
   return;
  }
  
  this.$object.removeEventListener('transitionend', this.boundEvent);
  
 this.is_running = false;
}


// Init it
var x = new RandomObjectMover(document.getElementById('a'), window);


// Toolbar stuff
document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', function(){
 x.start();
});
document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', function(){
 x.stop();
});
document.getElementById('speed').addEventListener('keyup', function(){
  if (parseInt(this.value) > 3000 ) {
   alert('Don\'t be stupid, stupid');
    this.value = 250;
  }
 x.setSpeed(parseInt(this.value));
});


// Start it off

x.start();
```

```css
div#toolbar {
  position:fixed;
  background:#20262F;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 10px
}
div#a {
width: 50px;
height:50px;
background-color:red;
position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="toolbar">
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
<input type="number" value="250" id="speed" />
</div>
<div id='a'></div>
```

Comment: That speed modifier worked great!  (If you lived locally I'd give you a cookie.)
Ya know, I understand what's going on in the code when I read it, but I would definitely not have been able to create it myself.  You guys are awesome!

Comment: So the code worked in jsfiddle, but as soon as I plugged it into Dreamweaver something is off.  I've got all my CSS and JQ internally as to only share one file, but something is strange.  I literally copied and pasted everything, but it's still not working.  Here is a copy of my code (sorry, can't indent on this website): http://tinytext.org/YmXT#
Any idea why it might not be working?
I plugged in that alert and it's not even making it into that block for me.

Comment: It's a weird one, but do this. the end brace (squiggly bracket } ) on the calcSpeed function. Delete that and re-add it by typing it in on your keyboard. Save it then re-test your script. Looks like it's copied the ending brace on that function in a weird way. So you just need to re-type that character

Comment: That worked!  A) How did you figure that was the problem?  and B) Any idea why/how that happened?

Comment: A) If you open up console (any javascript developers most essential in-browser tool of course, hit F12 if you have no idea what im on about), you get an illegal token error. Usually it means theres a bad character, and there's only one character on that line.

B) Happens often when you copy and paste code, differences in encoding and what not. Such as if something has been passed through htmlspecialchars in PHP to make it safe to users. It looks and copy and pastes fine, but its actually a string of characters rather than just one if you open it up in a very basic editor.

Comment: But more importantly. it's just experience. Everyone has their own ways of debugging. Mine is quite destructive as i tend to go for the "delete large blocks until it works, then put the code back in piece by piece" method when i've exhausted the obvious debugging methods. In javascript, using the browsers console (IE's is not so good, use chrome or firefox) and google.com will usually fix 90% of any issues you find quite quickly (although this one was a doozey if you've never seen it before to be fair)

Comment: I followed the example and slightly modified it and found that with each call animate in the document.ready body, the div becomes increasing laggy. Any way to fix that?

Comment: @Edasaur: Could you provide a JSFiddle and maybe what browser (and version) your using. There's some small optimisations you could make, but it may just be your browser/computer limiting things. I have google chrome running on a pretty beefy macbook and i just modified the jsfiddle from my post to look like this http://jsfiddle.net/Jd8uY/  ... Turned the speed up really high in that fiddle and loads more div's and doesn't lag for me.

Comment: @Edasaur: Another option would be to use the greensock tweening library. It's miles more performant that jquery's animate. Here's a quick idea of how it works ( http://jsfiddle.net/q65j7/ ), obviously i've just replaced the animate bit of the code with the tween required, but there's a lot of optimisations you can do (the original code isn't at all optimal anyway, i just knocked it together as an example). Depending on how random you want it you could use timeline's to pre-generate a looping track for each div, or use the same track for every div and use a start delay

Comment: @Lee: http://jsfiddle.net/g4d3u/1/ is what it looks like right now. It seems like with each recursive call of animate, each subsequent div begins to slow down. Not entirely sure about optimization in js/jquery, but I'll give greensock tweening a shot!

Comment: @Lee: Okay nevermind. I fixed my problem. It was related to the speed function. I had them set as different speeds.

Comment: I am too doing animation and here is my js bin but the animation is is stucking and consuming lots of memory:http://jsbin.com/kakoritate/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: At slow speed its very jerky, is there anyway to make it smoother at slow speed?

Comment: Tried animating the box within a fixed width/height parent element with the CSS version but it doesn't work. No errors thrown either. Seems it only works if setting the container to "window". Any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: @Ivan I never tested anything but a window container. It's because only window supports innerHeight. I've updated the code snippet to fix the container dimensions to work with non-window. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/d67Lztmc/

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
function moveDiv() {
    var $span = $("#random");

    $span.fadeOut(1000, function() {
        var maxLeft = $(window).width() - $span.width();
        var maxTop = $(window).height() - $span.height();
        var leftPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxLeft + 1))
        var topPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxTop + 1))

        $span.css({ left: leftPos, top: topPos }).fadeIn(1000);
    });
};

moveDiv();
setInterval(moveDiv, 5000);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Z7HE/3/)

Comment: This is exactly what I want, except I need to to be a smooth animation, not jumpy.  I'll have to see what everyone else posted, but thanks!!

Comment: @Ephraim no problem - I've just updated the code and fiddle so that it fade in and out smoothly.

Comment: Great, but how make multiple? if i have 30 images and 5 only must be showed in one time

Answer (score 6):

well you'll need to capture the dimensions of the `window`

then you'll need to `generate random numbers` `<=` the `height` and `width` of the `screen` (minus the `width`/`height` of the `box`)

give the box an `absolute` position, and give the box have the generated `x`,`y` `coordinates`

then set a timer to call `this function` again.

:)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    randoBox = {
      width:$("body").width(),
      height:$("body").height(),
      x:0,
      y:0,
      el:null,
      time:1000,
      state:"active",
      init: function(){
        el = $(document.createElement('div'));
        el.attr("style","position:absolute;left:"+this.x+";top:"+this.y+";");
        el.html("DVD")            
        el.height(100);
        el.width(100);
        $("body").append(el);
      },
      move:function(){
        this.y = Math.random()*this.height+1;
        this.x = Math.random()*this.width+1;
        el.attr("style","position:absolute;left:"+this.x+";top:"+this.y+";");            
      },
      run:function(state){
        if (this.state == "active" || state){
          this.move();
          setTimeout(function(){this.run()},this.time);
        }
      }
    }
    randoBox.init();
    randoBox.run(true);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** Added random movement, like DVD idle screen but can bounce anywhere.

http://jsfiddle.net/ryXBM/2/

```
dirR = "+=2";
dirL = "+=2";

function moveDir() {
 if (Math.random() > 0.95) {
  swapDirL();
 }
 if (Math.random() < 0.05) {
  swapDirR();
 }
}

function swapDirL() {
    dirL == "+=2" ? dirL = "-=2" : dirL = "+=2"; 
}

function swapDirR() {
    dirR == "+=2" ? dirR = "-=2" : dirR = "+=2";   
}

setInterval (function() { $("#d").css("left", dirL); $("#d").css("top", dirR); moveDir(); } , 50)​
```

**CSS**

```
#d { position: absolute;
 left: 100px;
 top: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: #fce;   
}​
```

Comment: Leaving the randomness implementation to the questioner

Comment: Therefore only partially answering the question.  If the OP asked how to move an element then this would be an acceptable answer.

Comment: This looks petty random to me, which means it will look random to a user.  Still not the exact effect I'm looking for though, but I will play around with this code and see what I can tweak.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [jQuery Slide](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide) and [Math.random()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp), generating one random number to use as the distance to move and another random number to base your decision on which direction to move in.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to specify the borders of the animation - what is the maximum values for the `top` and `left` attributes...
After that all you need is the `.animate()` function to be called again and again...

Something like this should work -

```
var maxLeft = _left_border - $('#selectedElement').width(); // counter intuitively this is actually the right border
var maxTop = _top_border  - $('#selectedElement').height();
var animationDurration = _duration;

function randomAnimation(){
  var randomLeft = Math.floor(Math.random()*maxLeft);
  var randomTop = Math.floor(Math.random()*maxTop);

  $('#selectedElement').animate({
     left: randomLeft,
     top: randomTop
   }, animationDurration, function() {
     randomAnimation();
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="sample1.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('.btn').mouseover(function(){
                        $(this).css({
                            left:(Math.random()*$(window).width()-20),
                            top:(Math.random()*$(window).height()-20),      
                        });
                    });              
            });
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div class="btn" style="position: absolute">button</div>
    </body>
</html>
```