# jquery animate memory problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks, jquery-animate

I have used jQuery .animate (Inspiration from [how to get a div to randomly move around a page (using jQuery or CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385950/how-to-get-a-div-to-randomly-move-around-a-page-using-jquery-or-css) ) to animate a number of divs.
I have always used javascript, not jQuery as a rule so am a little unsure of my footing here. Hence needing the snippet initially.

My code performs exactly as expected but it seems I have a memory leak somewhere, and over time (abut 10 minutes) the browser - (IE, chrome and FF) will accrue about 500MB RAM usage.

I cannot fathom why, as there are no queued instructions - as helped by the `setTimeout` - and no loading images etc.

(The `IF` statement is to allow me to at some other time - alter the class to my 50 '#z' divs, and turn off animation.)

Anyone know about debugging these kind of issues? It crashes the browser over time so is essentially useless as a production page as is. 
One more thing, FF's online crash reports are flipping awful, there's been no 'dump' after submitting, and the issue is less pronounced on chrome/IE - so no crash reports available. 
Will update as soon as I get something useful.

```
function animateDiv() {
    for (z = 0; z < 50; z++) {
        var newq = makeNewPosition();
        var oldq = $("#" + z).position()
        var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.left], newq);

        if (document.getElementById(z).class != "b") {
            $("#" + z).animate({
                left: newq
            }, speed, function() {});
        }
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        animateDiv();
    }, 0.1);
}

function makeNewPosition() {
    var w = $('#content').width() - 25;
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);    
    return [nw];
}

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {
    var y = Math.abs(prev - next);
    var greatest = y;
    var speedModifier = 0.1;
    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);
    return speed;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly. It will make it much easier for you and others to read.

Comment: Thats as true in life as it is on Stack. Pretty deep! Thanks Rory.

Comment: Try it like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ncrAZ/5/), looks to me like 0,1 milliseconds is a little optimistic for that reccurring timeout  ???

Comment: Adeneo, i am running the code now. 10mins will tell. What would reformatting the IF have done there?

Comment: Still running hot. 0-250Mb in only 2minutes. Will try a 10 timeout, will run like a slug but may not leak

Comment: @TechiePhil - I actually updated the fiddle to do what jfriend00 wrote below, run the function again when the animation is complete, but that may not be what you want, but running them all at once is probably part of the issue, and there is some other weirdness with that code?

Comment: @TechiePhil - the timeout is outside the for loop, and executes as soon as the browser is ready, and keeps piling on 50 animations every 0,1ms, which is'nt possible as most browsers will need atleast 100ms just to run the function and start over again, and you pile up millions of animations within a few seconds, and as jfriend just wrote, running the function in the complete handler will also just run it 50 more times etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `animateDiv()`, you are both starting an animation and setting a timeout to start the next animation for 0.1 milliseconds from now.  If your animation is longer than 0.1 milliseconds (which it probably is), then your animations will pile up infinitely, eventually killing the browser.  Also, `setTimeout()` takes an integer number of milliseconds, not a decimal number of seconds.

Since I doubt your intention is to have multiple animations on the exact same object all running at the same time, you should start the next animation for one object using the completion function of the previous animation, not using a timer.  This would guarantee that they never pile up.  For safety's sake, you could also issue a `.stop(true)` on the object before starting the next animation to make sure whatever came before is done/stopped before starting the next animation, again making sure they can never accumulate indefinitely.

You could use something like this to fix the problem and be safe:

```
function animateDiv() {

    function animateItem(item) {
        if (!item.hasClass("b")) {
            var newq = makeNewPosition();
            var oldq = item.position()
            var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.left], newq);
            // make sure animations can never accumulate and 
            // then start the next one
            item.stop(true).animate({
                left: newq
            }, speed, function() {
                // run next animation on this object when this one finishes
                animateItem(item);
            });
        }

    }
    // start all animations
    for (z = 0; z < 50; z++) {
        animateItem($("#" + z));
    }
}
```

Comment: The way i read my current code, is i currently have 50 iterations of an animation running, and once complete - timeout to allow other instructions to complete, then restart function. Is this not the case then?

Comment: Nope, the animations are asynchronous, so you just keep running 50 animations every 0,1ms, or in other words a shitload of animations every second.

Comment: @TechiePhil - your code starts 50 animations every 0.1 milliseconds.  It does not wait for the previous animation to finish before starting the next one so they pile up indefinitely eventually overwhelming the browser.

Comment: It takes up to 1second to complete animation of some of the divs, but others complete in less than half a second. If i alter the setTimeout to be more than half a second, would i have stalling divs in some instances, and queued instructions in others then?

Comment: @TechiePhil - please read my answer which explains that the SAFE way to start the next item's animation is to start it only when the previous animation has finished.  If you insist on using a setTimeout() to start the next round of animations, then you MUST set the time for that to be longer than any animation can possibly take (in milliseconds) AND you should insert `.stop(true)` so your animations can never accumulate and cause this problem.

Comment: I added a code example that would be safe and would never have a stalled item as the next animation for a given item starts exactly when the previous animation finishes, regardless of how long the animation took.

Comment: Thanks Jfriend, i am running your code right now to ensure the problem has gone. Much Appreciated. So if i did leave it with setTimeout, i would have to have stalling Divs (as well as any other problems) then?

Comment: Seems to be working like a charm jfriend00. Like i say, animations until now have been gifs and flash. Had the option of HTML5 canvas but i'd still have had to overlay divs for a hyperlink so i chose to dive into jQuery