# Floating divs - adding more than one to existing script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm using [this page](http://prehuman.tumblr.com) to act as a portal of my web projects. The jsfiddle script posted as the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385950/how-to-get-a-div-to-randomly-move-around-a-page-using-jquery-or-css) is essentially what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure how to make *multiple* divs slide simultaneously around the window. I would like to have divs with text links in them like the "WEIRD CREEP" one. I tried editing it myself to no avail, as my knowledge of script is poor.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/Xw29r/865/

I changed the animateDiv to take in an obj

```
function animateDiv(obj){
var newq = makeNewPosition();
var oldq = $(obj).offset();
var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

$(obj).animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
  animateDiv(obj);        
});
```

};

and I called .each on all divs

```
$("div").each(function(i,v){animateDiv(v)});
```

Comment: Yeah I saw that... Upvote for coming up with the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".example_selector").each(function() {
         animateDiv($(this));
    });
});
```

See full example at the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cfLG8/2/