# Moving a box to a random position with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I am looking for a way to implement the exact functionality from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10386178) using angularjs: Specifically, for a box (div) to move randomly around a screen, while being animated.  Currently I have tried

```
myApp.directive("ngSlider", function($window) {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        var animateDiv = function(newq) {
            var oldRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
            var oldq = [oldRect.top, oldRect.left];
            if (oldq != newq){
                var dir = calcDir([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);
                element.moveTo(oldq.left + dir[0], oldq.top + dir[1]);
                setTimeout(animateDiv(newq), 100);
            }
        };

        var makeNewPosition = function() {
            // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
            var window = angular.element($window);
            var h = window.height() - 50;
            var w = window.width() - 50;

            var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
            var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

            return [nh,nw];

        };


        function calcDir(prev, next) {
            var x = prev[1] - next[1];
            var y = prev[0] - next[0];
            var norm = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
            return [x/norm, y/norm];
        }
        var newq = makeNewPosition();
        animateDiv(newq);
    }
  };
});
```

There appears to be quite a bit wrong with this, from an angular point of view.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like to take advantage of CSS in situations like this.

- absolutely position your div
- use `ng-style` to bind `top` and `left` attributes to some in-scope variable
- randomly change the `top` and `left` attributes of this in-scope variable
- use CSS transitions on `top` and `left` attributes to animate it for you

I made a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6S1jWxj3ygFIi1SHgXwp?p=preview)! Visit Kentucky!