# Trigger on mouse move

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been using a snippet of code I found to create some divs moving randomly around the screen. However, this gets quite confusing after a while, and as such I'd like it to only trigger their movement when the mouse/cursor is being moved.

My jQuery skills are slim to none, so some guidance would be highly appreciated!

My code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    animateElem('.a');
    animateElem('.b');
    animateElem('.c');
    animateElem('.d');

});

function makeNewPosition(){

// Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
var h = jQuery(window).height() - 50;
var w = jQuery(window).width() - 50;

var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

return [nh,nw];    

}

function animateElem(elem){
var newq = makeNewPosition();
var oldq = jQuery('.a').offset();
var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

jQuery(elem).animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
  animateElem(elem);        
});

};

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

var speedModifier = 0.2;

var speed = Math.ceil(greatest/speedModifier);

return speed;

}
```

My jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FjM5j/

Original post here: [how to get a div to randomly move around a page (using jQuery or CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385950/how-to-get-a-div-to-randomly-move-around-a-page-using-jquery-or-css)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu can use `$(document).mousemove()`. Also use `.stop()` for stopping the previous animate call method

```
function animateElem(elem){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    var oldq = jQuery('.a').offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

    jQuery(elem).stop().animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
    //  animateElem(elem);        
    });

};

$(document).mousemove(function( event ) {
      animateElem('.a');
        animateElem('.b');
        animateElem('.c');
        animateElem('.d');

});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FjM5j/4/)

Answer (score 0):

By changing the `jQuery(document).ready(function($){` to `jQuery(document).mousemove(function($){`, your function will be initiated when the mouse is moved instead of when the page is loaded.

Here's a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/FjM5j/1/