# jQuery animate "step" option breaking animation/speed settings

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm working with the code originally found in this question: [how to get a div to randomly move around a page (using jQuery or CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385950/how-to-get-a-div-to-randomly-move-around-a-page-using-jquery-or-css)

I have edited the code to work with a varying number of divs, instead of just one. Here is a fiddle of my code with two moving divs: http://jsfiddle.net/FireBot/ordkyjmx/. In the end, there will be between five and ten divs moving around the page.

```
function animateOrbs(){
$('.orb').each(function(){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    var oldq = $(this).offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

    $(this).animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
        animateOrbs();
    });
});
}
```

I need collision detection on all of the moving divs so they never overlap and instead stop or bounce off each other. From my research, it sounds like I need to compare the positions of all my animated divs and check if any of them are the same. As a starting point, I thought I would use the jQuery animate "step" option to get the positions of the divs as they move and print the numbers in each respective div.

```
function animateOrbs(){
$('.orb').each(function(){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    var oldq = $(this).offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

    $(this).animate(
        {top: newq[0], left: newq[1]},
        {step: function(){
            var pos = $(this).position();
            var posRight = pos.left + $(this).width();
            var posBottom = pos.top + $(this).height();

            var posData ='Top: ' + pos.top.toFixed(0) + '<br />Left: ' + pos.left.toFixed(0) + '<br />Right: ' + posRight.toFixed(0) + '<br />Bottom: ' + posBottom;

            $(this).html('<div>' + posData + '</div>');
        }}, 
        speed, 
        function(){
            animateOrbs();
        }
    );
});
}
```

With the step code in place, the animation now seems to ignore the speed setting and no longer repeats. Here is a fiddle of the same script with the step option in place: http://jsfiddle.net/FireBot/u6x84ho9/

I would like the divs to move slowly around the screen, like in my first fiddle, while still printing their current position as they move around. I've checked and double checked my code, and from what I can tell my "step" implementation matches the example here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/. I appreciate any help!

As an aside, if I'm going in the completely wrong direction for collision detection, please let me know, too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Your fiddle doesn't work because you you use a wrong signature for `.animate`. As the [link you gave youself](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) provides, using `step` requires the second signature:

```
$("selector").animate(properties, options);
```

Both arguments must be objects and there are no more arguments, so you have to put step-function, speed, callback-function and all others into the options object like so:

```
$(this).animate(
    {top: newq[0], left: newq[1]}, // properties object
    {                              // open options object
        step: function() {/* your stepping code */},
        duration: speed,
        complete : animateOrbs // since animateOrbs is a function there's no wrapping function needed
        // more options, use the names predefined by jQuery!
    }                              // close options object
); // close animate
```

Updated [FIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/u6x84ho9/7/).

2) Only some hints about the collision detection:

In generally you're on the right way to a collision detection. It would be enough (and really enough math to do) to detect if one of the edges or corners are inside the boundaries of another div. Therefore you must have acess to the values of the other divs. You should think about storing all data in an array or object outside your function.