# Moving multiple div's randomly around a page jQuery JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385950/how-to-get-a-div-to-randomly-move-around-a-page-using-jquery-or-css) really very helpful and it is almost what I want to achieve

The problem is I want multiple div moving around a page, how can this be modified to allow for multiple elements moving randomly?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
animateDiv();

});

function makeNewPosition(){

// Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
var h = $(window).height() - 50;
var w = $(window).width() - 50;

var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

return [nh,nw];    

}

function animateDiv(){
var newq = makeNewPosition();
var oldq = $('.a').offset();
var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

$('.a').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
  animateDiv();        
});

};

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

var speedModifier = .8;

var speed = Math.ceil(greatest/speedModifier);

return speed;

}
```

In this codepen I've made a new function targeting a new class but its drawing out the same movement.

http://codepen.io/Alex/pen/OPPBmX

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to contain the functionality within a function, and call that function multiple times.

You can have a containing div which all divs will be appended to:

```
<div class="animatedDivs"></div>
```

Then inside the function you can create a div, append it to that div, and animate it:

```
function newDiv() {
    //Create
    var $div = $("<div class='a'>");

    //Append
    $(".animatedDivs").append($div);

    //Animate
    animateDiv();    

    function animateDiv(){
        //same code with $('.a') replaced by $div
    };

}

function makeNewPosition(){
    //same code
}

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {
    //same code
}
```

Then you can create as many as you want:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    newDiv();
    newDiv();
    //etc...
});
```

Fiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9agtb339/1/

Answer (score 1):

Your wrong:

> You animate ".a" in your `animateDivTwo` function, seems like you want target ".b" here
>   You call `animateDiv` in `animateDivTwo` function

So, `animateDivTwo` calls once only

I correct your [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myyzXV)

Answer (score 1):

Please look into this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xw29r/3448/).
**Updated**

```
<div class='a' name="animate"></div>
<div class='b' name="animate"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div[name=animate]").each(function(){
        animateDiv($(this));
    });
});


function animateDiv(c){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    $(c).animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, function(){
      animateDiv(c);        
    });

};
```

**css**

```
div.a, div.b {
     width: 50px;
     height:50px;
      background-color:red;
     position:fixed;

    }
    div.b{
        background-color:green;
    }
```

This is just an Idea to start with.

**UPDATE**

In this following updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xw29r/3448/) I have created three `Div`. So this is the best way to add any number of divs. All that you have to do is add css. Infact we can randomize that too.

Answer (score 1):

I made some modifications on your code pen page and came up with an solution I believe:

I made all the divs the same class.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPPOXg

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    animateDiv();
    animateDivTwo();

});

function makeNewPosition(){

    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    var h = $(window).height() - 50;
    var w = $(window).width() - 50;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh,nw];    

}

function animateDiv(element){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    var oldq = $('.a').offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

    $(element).animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
      animateDiv(element);        
    });

};

function animateDivTwo(){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    var oldq = $('.a').offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

    $('.a').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
      animateDiv(this);        
    });

};

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

    var speedModifier = .4;

    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest/speedModifier);

    return speed;

}
```