# Animate children of a div that have been created within a function (with js or jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, children

I'm taking a coding class at school and am very new to javascript, so hopefully what I'm asking will make sense!

Right now I have a page where if you click an html button, an image of a worm appears in a div below it (called "bugs"). the same image appears each time you click the button. I've done this by having the button click call a function that creates an img element and adds it as a child of the div. the issue is I want the images to move randomly around the page or even just inside the div. I've found some code that will animate a div so it moves randomly using jQuery ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385950/how-to-get-a-div-to-randomly-move-around-a-page-using-jquery-or-css)), but I can't for the life of me figure out how to apply it to the images.

The js code that makes the images looks like this:

```
var BugSpace = document.getElementById("bugs");

function NewWorm(){
  WormPic = document.createElement("img");
  WormPic.src = "worm.png";
  BugSpace.appendChild(WormPic);
};
```

Most of my code is pieced together from various tutorials so is likely pretty convoluted. anyway, if anyone can figure this out I'll be eternally grateful :~)

Edit: I suppose I should further clarify that the code includes two other buttons to make two other types of bugs! I'd like to be able to have a few images of each bug moving on the page at once. I figure the best way to do this is to find a way to animate the children of the "bug" div? I am, however, wondering if the answer to my problem might turn out to be a complete reworking of the code I have now!

Comment: can you set a jsfiddle with your code please

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable using jQuery, then you can use the following solution.

You basically still animate the `div` and because the `img` is contained within the `div`, it will animate too.

All you need to do is call the `animateDiv()` function after you've added the image.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $button = $('#button');
    $bug = $('#bug');
    $wormimg = "<img src='http://bit.ly/1r7l5ns' class='worm'/>";

    $button.on('click', function(){
        $bug.html($wormimg);
        animateDiv();
    }); 
});
```

The `animateDiv()` function here is exactly the same as the link you've provided.

Have a look at the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3xgqogkk/

**EDIT (based on more information from the comments)**

So the **new** core javascript looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $button = $('#button');
    $bug = $('#bug');
    $wormimg = "<img src='http://bit.ly/1r7l5ns' class='worm'/>";

    $button.on('click', function(){
        $bug.append($wormimg); //Changed this to append so we can add more than 1
        animateDiv($bug.children().last()); 
        //We're basically passing the last worm you've added as a variable
    }); 
});
```

Which means you have to make some modifications to the `animateDiv()` method, which is now actually `animateDiv($worm)`

```
function animateDiv($worm){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    var oldq = $worm.offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

    $worm.animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
      animateDiv($worm);        
    }); 
};
```

The important thing is to understand everything that's happening here, so if you have any questions, just ask :)

The jsfiddle is also updated: http://jsfiddle.net/3xgqogkk/

Comment: This is excellent, thanks a bunch! My only issue is that I'd like to be able to have multiple moving worms created with the button. I'm wondering if that's even a possibility with the way I have my code set up.

Comment: Yes it is. Question is, do you want them all inside one div? Or individual divs?

Comment: I feel like I'd have an easier time keeping track if they were all in one div.

Comment: Hey, sorry for not getting back to you! I've been fiddling around with it and I still can't seem to get it working. The initial code where you animated the div worked, but it won't animate the div's children